# CSS hover selector do not work

Tags: css

I want that when I hover [.area] class, [.button] class changes but It does not work. What can i do?

Here is my code

```
#content { float:left; margin:0 20px 20px 0; }
.area { z-index:0; position:relative; border-radius:5px; border:3px #09B2D2 solid; height:430px; width:245px; transition: all .5s; }
.area:hover { background:#09b2d2; }
.area:hover .words { color:#fff; }
.head { background:#09b2d2; width:245px; margin-top:25px; text-align:center; font-family:Segoe UI; font-size:30px; text-transform:uppercase; padding:3px 0; font-weight:bold; color:#fff; }
.words { margin-top:25px; line-height:40px; text-align:center; color:#09b2d2; font-family:Segoe UI; font-weight:bold; transition: all .5s; }
.button { z-index:1; transition: all .5s; left:57px; background:#fff; top:-20px; border-radius:3px; border:2px solid #09B2D2; width: 125px; height: 40px; position:relative; text-align:center; }
.button:hover { background:#09b2d2; }
.button:hover .h1 { opacity:0; }
.button:hover .h2 { opacity:100; }
.h1 { transition: all .5s; z-index:2; margin:4px 0 0 -32px; font-weight:bold; color:#09B2D2; font-family:Segoe UI; font-size:20px; position:absolute; }
.h2 { margin:5px 0 0 -36px; transition: all .5s; z-index:2; opacity:0; font-weight:bold; color:#fff; font-family:Segoe UI; font-size:20px; position:absolute; }
.h2 > a { color:#fff; text-decoration:none;}

<div id="content">
    <div class="area">
        <div class="head">Başlangıç</div>
        <div class="words">Wordpress Teknolojisi</br>1 Yıl Alan Adı Tescili</br>500 MB Hosting</br></br>Seo Desteği</br>Ücretsiz Destek</br>Kontrol Paneli</div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
    <span class="h1">100 TL</span>
    <span class="h2"><a href="#">Satın Al</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
.area:hover + .button {
    /* CSS here */
}
```

This styles the `.button` element when the previous-sibling `.area` is hovered-over.

The reason your original code "didn't work" is because there was, apparently, no CSS selector targeting the `.area:hover` or specifying the `.button` element in relation to that element.

To make it less restrictive:

```
.area:hover ~ .button {
    /* CSS here */
}
```

This will style any sibling `.button` element that appears later in the DOM than the `.area` element that's hovered.

The `+` is the adjacent-sibling combinator (which will select *only* the `.button` element that appears *immediately* after the `.area`), the `~` is the general-sibling combinator, which will select *all* `.button` elements that follow the `.area` eleent.

References:

- [CSS sibling combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#sibling-combinators).

Comment: True but should probably come with a warning as to why it's so fragile

Comment: there is anyone to help me ?

Comment: They're not siblings, are they? The `.h1` is a descendant of the `.button` which is a sibling of `.area`, use the appropriate selector: [`.area:hover ~ .button .h1`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/75ZyM/).